# Data retrieval fails after clearing Local

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm writing unit tests for entity framework, using the Effort in memory db.

In one set of tests the EF part creates an object and adds some existing objects to a child list in it (think Master / Detail).  Then it SavesChanges

In the unit test I then retrieve the record from EF and check that it actually got there and the children are in place:  they are.

However, I want to be sure that I'm not just reading the data from the cache and that it actually got persisted.  So I Clear() the Local cache in the DbSet.

When I do this, I retrieve the main record OK, but the child records are NOT retrieved.

This is true if I run the code against SQL Server as well as Effort (so it's not Effort).

If I dispose the context and create a new one, the same method retrieves the data correctly include the children.

So something about clearing the local cache is interfering with the data retrieval.  I've tried clearing just cache for the main record and also for both that and the child records - no difference.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I should add that, in some circumstances (with other tests and objects), clearing the cache has the expected effect (full records are retrieved).  This particular main record is part of a Table Per Hierarchy set which may be a factor.